# How to make GPIO init before MII init

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I want to make GPIO-driven reset on 2 PHY chips inside DUAL EMAC on TI AM3352.
Because drivers don't have the ability, I have made a mod in *mdio_bus.c* driver, function `mdiobus_register_gpiod()`:

```c
if (gpiod == NULL && mdiodev->bus && mdiodev->bus->dev.of_node) {           
    gpiod = fwnode_get_named_gpiod(&mdiodev->bus->dev.of_node->fwnode,
                       "phy-reset-gpios", mdiodev->addr, GPIOD_OUT_LOW,
                       "PHY reset");                        
    if (gpiod)
        printk("found gpiod for addr=%d\n", mdiodev->addr);                         
}

mdiodev->reset = gpiod;
```

this is my device tree with added feature:

```dts
&cpsw_emac0 {
    status = "okay";
    phy_id = <&davinci_mdio>, <0>;
    phy-mode = "mii";
    dual_emac_res_vlan = <1>;   
};

&cpsw_emac1 {
    status = "okay";
    phy_id = <&davinci_mdio>, <1>;
    phy-mode = "mii";
    dual_emac_res_vlan = <2>;   
};

&davinci_mdio {
    status = "okay";
    phy-reset-gpios = <&gpio1 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>, <&gpio1 1 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&mdio_pins_default>;
};

&mac {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&phy1_pins_default>,<&phy2_pins_default>;
    dual_emac = <1>;
};
```

However GPIO controller is initialized long after MDIO drivers, so the mdio-bus cannot find GPIO chips.

Is it possible to initialize GPIO earlier? Where is this priority configured?

Comment: Driver probe request functions can return (or propagate) an `-EPROBE_DEFER` error if some resource it is looking for is not available yet. The probe function should still clean up after itself as it should do for any other error. See the discussion of `-EPROBE_DEFER` in the [Callbacks](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/driver-model/driver.html#callbacks) section of [Device Drivers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/driver-model/driver.html).

Comment: Use simple `devm_gpiod_get(&mdiodev->bus->dev, ...);`